# Unable to use CPAN with proxy authentication. Getting keep_alive error

Tags: perl, cpan, keep-alive

I am unable to install any module in perl which required proxy authentication.
I configured perl with proxy credentials using cpan[2]> o conf init /proxy/

I get below error when i try to install any package.
Please help.

```
cpan[4]> i 'XML::RAI'
←[32mGoing to read 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'←[0m
←[32m  Database was generated on Wed, 26 Sep 2012 10:43:03 GMT←[0m
←[32mFetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz←[0m
The keep_alive option must be enabled for NTLM authentication to work.  NTLM authentication aborted.
Catching error: "Undefined subroutine &CPAN::HTTP::Credentials::_clear_non_proxy_credentials called at C:\\Perl\\lib/CPAN/HTTP/Cred
ne 391
        CPAN::shell() called at C:/Perl/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 295
        App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at C:/Perl/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 364
        App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at C:\Perl\bin/cpan.bat line 24
←[32m←[0m
```

Uma Mahesh

Comment: Do you find anything in this error message to be meaningful: The keep_alive option must be enabled for NTLM authentication to work.  NTLM authentication aborted.

Comment: For instance, are you trying to authenticate to your proxy via NTLM?

Comment: @lenjaffe I believe, yes. When i use LWP as below, its working
For CPAN Config, i have provided same creds using o conf and submit to commit.


my $request = new HTTP::Request('GET', $url);
$request->proxy_authorization_basic( $USERNAME, $PASSWORD );

my $response = $ua->request($request);

Comment: Do you have the keep_alive option enabled?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I'm behind an NTLM proxy. I fixed it by running [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) which authenticates using NTLM, and set my cpan config to that (e.g. localhost:3128)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set proxy settings from the cpan

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[2]> o conf init /proxy/
Your ftp_proxy? [a.b.c.d] a.b.c.d:port
Your http_proxy? [a.b.c.d] a.b.c.d:port
Your no_proxy? [] a.b.c.d:port
cpan[3]> o conf commit
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! 
More info -- you can edit this information afterward in ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm if it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be triggered if your stored password is incorrect.